# Getting different entries with different starting Char

Tags: sql, sqlite

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIAvx.png)

Hey I'm looking to do a query which allows me to see how many citties have starting phone number with number 6 and the other between 7-9

```
SELECT COUNT(Ciudad) AS "T.Fijos", Ciudad
FROM  "BBDD.CLIENTES"WHERE Teléfono LIKE "9%"
GROUP BY Ciudad
```

that query only shows me phone number starting with 9 I need to do all in one query

Comment: What does *the other between 7-9* mean? Post sample data and expected results as text and not images to clarify.

Comment: I mean, how many phone number starts with 6 and  with any number between 7-9 for each city. For example, Barcelona may have 2 phone numbers starting with 6 and 6 phone numbers starting with 7, 8 or 9.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following.

However, I wonder whether your FROM should in fact be `FROM "BBDD"."CLIENTES"`. By wrapping the entire name in double-quotes in that way, you are saying that the table name is "BBBD.CLIENTES" and not specifying a schema.

Unfortunately I am unable to test this on SQLite, but it should be generally OK.

We can use a common table expression (CTE - the WITH... part) to create a temporary view of the data including a new column for the starting digit.

Then we can use CASE WHEN ... to check what the start digit is and return some text describing that digit.

```
WITH t
AS
(
SELECT Ciudad,
       "Teléfono",
       CAST(SUBSTR(Teléfono,1,1) AS integer) AS starting_digit
FROM "BBDD.CLIENTES"
)
SELECT Ciudad,
       'Teléfono starts with ' || 
        CASE 
          WHEN starting_digit = 6 THEN '6'
          WHEN starting_digit BETWEEN 7 AND 9 THEN '7, 8 or 9'
          ELSE 'something else'
        END AS phone_start,
        COUNT(*) AS count_of_phone_numbers
FROM t
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```